# Combine Audio with Video(without ffmpeg) - Java

Tags: java, jmf

I am building an applet to capture screen and microphone input (audio). I am able to record these files separately but could not find a way to combine these files to make a new video with audio.

Video file is in `.mov` format and audio is in `.wav` format. They have exact same length.

Is there any way to combine these files? I have tried Java but could not find a way to combine two files.

Also I have to do it without `ffmpeg` since it needs to be installed on client side.

Comment: Check the Movie Maker e.g. of the [Monte Media Library](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/).  It will do 20FPS screen capture with sound.  *"Also I have to do it without ffmpeg since it needs to be installed on client side."* If not 'install' then you are going to need to make available  some non-J2SE classes.  Get used to the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void mergeFiles() {
    try {   
        DataSource videoDataSource = javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(oml.getURL()); //your video file
        DataSource audioDataSource = javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(realAudioFile.toURI().toURL()); // your audio file
        DataSource mixedDataSource = null; // data source to combine video with audio
        DataSource arrayDataSource[] = new DataSource[2]; //data source array
        DataSource outputDataSource = null; // file to output

        DataSink outputDataSink = null; // datasink for output file

        MediaLocator videoLocator = new MediaLocator(oml.getURL()); //media locator for video 
        MediaLocator audioLocator = new MediaLocator(realAudioFile.toURI().toURL()); //media locator for audio

        FileTypeDescriptor outputType = new FileTypeDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME); //output video format type

        Format outputFormat[] = new Format[2]; //format array 
        VideoFormat videoFormat = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG); // output video codec MPEG does not work on windows
        javax.media.format.AudioFormat audioMediaFormat = new javax.media.format.AudioFormat(
                javax.media.format.AudioFormat.LINEAR, 44100, 16, 1); //audio format


        outputFormat[0] = videoFormat;
        outputFormat[1] = audioMediaFormat;

        //create processors for each file
        Processor videoProcessor = Manager.createProcessor(videoDataSource); 
        Processor audioProcessor = Manager.createProcessor(audioDataSource);
        Processor processor = null;

        //start video and audio processors
        videoProcessor.realize();
        audioProcessor.realize();
        //wait till they are realized
        while(videoProcessor.getState() != 300 && audioProcessor.getState() != 300) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        //get processors dataoutputs to merge
        arrayDataSource[0] = videoProcessor.getDataOutput();
        arrayDataSource[1] = audioProcessor.getDataOutput();

        videoProcessor.start();
        audioProcessor.start();

        //create merging data source
        mixedDataSource = javax.media.Manager.createMergingDataSource(arrayDataSource);
        mixedDataSource.connect();
        mixedDataSource.start();
        //init final processor to create merged file
        ProcessorModel processorModel = new ProcessorModel(mixedDataSource, outputFormat, outputType);
        processor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(processorModel);
        processor.addControllerListener(this);
        processor.configure();
        //wait till configured
        while(processor.getState() < 180) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }

        processor.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

        TrackControl tcs[] = processor.getTrackControls();
        Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();

        tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

        processor.realize();
        //wait till realized
        while(processor.getState() < 300) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        //create merged file and start writing media to it
        outputDataSource = processor.getDataOutput();
        MediaLocator outputLocator = new MediaLocator("file:/"+directory.getAbsolutePath()+"/yourmovfile.mov");
        outputDataSink = Manager.createDataSink(outputDataSource, outputLocator);
        outputDataSink.open();
        outputDataSink.addDataSinkListener(this);
        outputDataSink.start();
        processor.start();

        while(processor.getState() < 500) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        //wait until writing is done
        waitForFileDone();
        //dispose processor and datasink
        outputDataSink.stop();
        processor.stop();

        outputDataSink.close();
        processor.close();

    } catch (NoDataSourceException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IncompatibleSourceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoDataSinkException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoProcessorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CannotRealizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

Object waitFileSync = new Object();
boolean fileDone = false;
boolean fileSuccess = true;
Object waitSync = new Object();
boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

/**
 * Block until file writing is done.
 */
boolean waitForFileDone() {
    synchronized (waitFileSync) {
        try {
            while (!fileDone)
                waitFileSync.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return fileSuccess;
}

/**
 * Event handler for the file writer.
 */
public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

    if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            fileDone = true;
            waitFileSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            fileDone = true;
            fileSuccess = false;
            waitFileSync.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {
    if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            stateTransitionOK = true;
            waitSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            stateTransitionOK = false;
            waitSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
        evt.getSourceController().stop();
        evt.getSourceController().close();
    }

}
```

your class must implement ControllerListener, DataSinkListener. worked perfectly for me good video and audio sync (half a second shift in audio but not a problem for me).

Comment: can you tell what all packages or classes have to be imported?I tried using this but I get 48 errors. If you can post all the classes you imported, it would be great and more helpful.

Comment: sorry but i have lost the source code (formatted my pc) and i can't remember the packages i have used. I'll try to find them in my ftp server, if i can i'll send them to you if you still need them

Answer (score 2):

Import of the above code which may be help to someone:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.ConfigureCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerListener;
import javax.media.DataSink;
import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.IncompatibleSourceException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.NoDataSinkException;
import javax.media.NoDataSourceException;
import javax.media.NoProcessorException;
import javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.Processor;
import javax.media.ProcessorModel;
import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ResourceUnavailableEvent;
import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkErrorEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkEvent;    
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkListener;    
import javax.media.datasink.EndOfStreamEvent;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.FileTypeDescriptor;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Media Framework API (JMF). 
Check this 
[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-135148.html#what.)
.
Java Media Framework basics and tutorials are given at this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jmf/)