# Add audio track for jpegs to video in JMF (JpegImagesToMovie.java)

Tags: java, jmf

I am saving JPEGs of a video to files, I then send a vector with all the file names, and I can create a new video. I now want to add sound. I will probably need sound from both speakers and mic, but my main problem is how to save them to the video file. I have a feeling I can figure out how to grab them.

I encode the video with the following code:

```
/*
 * @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java   1.3 01/03/13
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
 * modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
 * provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
 * the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
 * which is disparaging to Sun.
 *
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
 * IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
 * NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
 * OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
 * LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
 * OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
 * aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
 * the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
 * facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
 * redistribute the Software for such purposes.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.ConfigureCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerListener;
import javax.media.DataSink;
import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.Processor;
import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ResourceUnavailableEvent;
import javax.media.Time;
import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkErrorEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkListener;
import javax.media.datasink.EndOfStreamEvent;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.FileTypeDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferDataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferStream;

import org.jitsi.util.OSUtils;
/**
 * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
 * QuickTime movie.
 */
public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

    public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector<String> inFiles,
            MediaLocator outML) throws MalformedURLException {
        ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,
                inFiles);

        Processor p;

        try {
            //System.err
            //      .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
            p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
            return false;
        }

        p.addControllerListener(this);

        // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
        // some processing options on the processor.
        p.configure();
        if (!waitForState(p, p.Configured)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
        p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
                FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

        // Query for the processor for supported formats.
        // Then set it on the processor.
        TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
        Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
        if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
            System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                    + tcs[0].getFormat());
            return false;
        }

        tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

        System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

        // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
        // realize it.
        p.realize();
        if (!waitForState(p, p.Realized)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
        DataSink dsink;
        if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
            System.err
                    .println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                            + outML);
            return false;
        }

        dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
        fileDone = false;

        System.out.println("Generating the video : "+outML.getURL().toString());

        // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
        try {
            p.start();
            dsink.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IO error during processing");
            return false;
        }

        // Wait for EndOfStream event.
        waitForFileDone();

        // Cleanup.
        try {
            dsink.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        p.removeControllerListener(this);

        System.out.println("Video creation completed!!!!!");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Create the DataSink.
     */
    DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

        DataSource ds;

        if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
            System.err
                    .println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
            return null;
        }

        DataSink dsink;

        try {
            System.err.println("- create DataSink for: outML: " + outML);
            System.err.println("- create DataSink for: p: " + p.toString());
            dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
            System.err.println("- create DataSink for: dSink: " + dsink.toString());
            dsink.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return dsink;
    }

    Object waitSync = new Object();
    boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

    /**
     * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
     * false if the transition failed.
     */
    boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            try {
                while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                    waitSync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return stateTransitionOK;
    }

    /**
     * Controller Listener.
     */
    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

        if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
                || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
                || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                stateTransitionOK = true;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                stateTransitionOK = false;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
            evt.getSourceController().stop();
            evt.getSourceController().close();
        }
    }

    Object waitFileSync = new Object();
    boolean fileDone = false;
    boolean fileSuccess = true;

    /**
     * Block until file writing is done.
     */
    boolean waitForFileDone() {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            try {
                while (!fileDone)
                    waitFileSync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return fileSuccess;
    }

    /**
     * Event handler for the file writer.
     */
    public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

        if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                fileDone = true;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                fileDone = true;
                fileSuccess = false;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    static void prUsage() {
        System.err
                .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie -w <width> -h <height> -f <frame rate> -o <output URL> <input JPEG file 1> <input JPEG file 2> ...");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    /**
     * Create a media locator from the given string.
     */
    static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

        MediaLocator ml;

        if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
            return ml;

        if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
            if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
                return ml;
        } else {
            String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + File.separator + url;
            if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
                return ml;
        }

        return null;
    }
    static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(File f){
        if (OSUtils.IS_MAC) {
            return createMediaLocator("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else {
            String urlString;
            try {
                urlString = f.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
                return createMediaLocator(urlString);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Inner classes.
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
     * stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
     */
    class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

        ImageSourceStream streams[];

        ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
            streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
            streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
        }

        public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
        }

        public MediaLocator getLocator() {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
         * without a container format.
         */
        public String getContentType() {
            return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
        }

        public void connect() {
        }

        public void disconnect() {
        }

        public void start() {
        }

        public void stop() {
        }

        /**
         * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
         */
        public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
            return streams;
        }

        /**
         * We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
         * frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
         */
        public Time getDuration() {
            return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
        }

        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String type) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
     */
    class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

        Vector images;
        int width, height;
        VideoFormat format;

        int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
        boolean ended = false;

        public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                Vector images) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.images = images;

            format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                    height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                    (float) frameRate);
        }

        /**
         * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
         */
        public boolean willReadBlock() {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
         * data.
         */
        public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

            // Check if we've finished all the frames.
            if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                //System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                buf.setEOM(true);
                buf.setOffset(0);
                buf.setLength(0);
                ended = true;
                return;
            }

            String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
            nextImage++;

            //System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

            // Open a random access file for the next image.
            RandomAccessFile raFile;
            raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

            byte data[] = null;

            // Check the input buffer type & size.

            if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
                data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

            // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
            if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
                data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
                buf.setData(data);
            }

            // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
            raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

            //System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

            buf.setOffset(0);
            buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
            buf.setFormat(format);
            buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | buf.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

            // Close the random access file.
            raFile.close();
        }

        /**
         * Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
         */
        public Format getFormat() {
            return format;
        }

        public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
            return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
        }

        public long getContentLength() {
            return 0;
        }

        public boolean endOfStream() {
            return ended;
        }

        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String type) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you find any solution ?

Comment: Sorry I don't recall having found anything - I'd have to search code and haven't found it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found a solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020074/8063735

Answer (score 0):

```
private void mergeFiles() {
    try {   
        DataSource videoDataSource = javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(oml.getURL()); //your video file
        DataSource audioDataSource = javax.media.Manager.createDataSource(realAudioFile.toURI().toURL()); // your audio file
        DataSource mixedDataSource = null; // data source to combine video with audio
        DataSource arrayDataSource[] = new DataSource[2]; //data source array
        DataSource outputDataSource = null; // file to output

        DataSink outputDataSink = null; // datasink for output file

        MediaLocator videoLocator = new MediaLocator(oml.getURL()); //media locator for video 
        MediaLocator audioLocator = new MediaLocator(realAudioFile.toURI().toURL()); //media locator for audio

        FileTypeDescriptor outputType = new FileTypeDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME); //output video format type

        Format outputFormat[] = new Format[2]; //format array 
        VideoFormat videoFormat = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG); // output video codec MPEG does not work on windows
        javax.media.format.AudioFormat audioMediaFormat = new javax.media.format.AudioFormat(
                javax.media.format.AudioFormat.LINEAR, 44100, 16, 1); //audio format


        outputFormat[0] = videoFormat;
        outputFormat[1] = audioMediaFormat;

        //create processors for each file
        Processor videoProcessor = Manager.createProcessor(videoDataSource); 
        Processor audioProcessor = Manager.createProcessor(audioDataSource);
        Processor processor = null;

        //start video and audio processors
        videoProcessor.realize();
        audioProcessor.realize();
        //wait till they are realized
        while(videoProcessor.getState() != 300 && audioProcessor.getState() != 300) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        //get processors dataoutputs to merge
        arrayDataSource[0] = videoProcessor.getDataOutput();
        arrayDataSource[1] = audioProcessor.getDataOutput();

        videoProcessor.start();
        audioProcessor.start();

        //create merging data source
        mixedDataSource = javax.media.Manager.createMergingDataSource(arrayDataSource);
        mixedDataSource.connect();
        mixedDataSource.start();
        //init final processor to create merged file
        ProcessorModel processorModel = new ProcessorModel(mixedDataSource, outputFormat, outputType);
        processor = Manager.createRealizedProcessor(processorModel);
        processor.addControllerListener(this);
        processor.configure();
        //wait till configured
        while(processor.getState() < 180) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }

        processor.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

        TrackControl tcs[] = processor.getTrackControls();
        Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();

        tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

        processor.realize();
        //wait till realized
        while(processor.getState() < 300) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        //create merged file and start writing media to it
        outputDataSource = processor.getDataOutput();
        MediaLocator outputLocator = new MediaLocator("file:/"+directory.getAbsolutePath()+"/yourmovfile.mov");
        outputDataSink = Manager.createDataSink(outputDataSource, outputLocator);
        outputDataSink.open();
        outputDataSink.addDataSinkListener(this);
        outputDataSink.start();
        processor.start();

        while(processor.getState() < 500) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        //wait until writing is done
        waitForFileDone();
        //dispose processor and datasink
        outputDataSink.stop();
        processor.stop();

        outputDataSink.close();
        processor.close();

    } catch (NoDataSourceException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IncompatibleSourceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoDataSinkException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoProcessorException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CannotRealizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

Object waitFileSync = new Object();
boolean fileDone = false;
boolean fileSuccess = true;
Object waitSync = new Object();
boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

/**
 * Block until file writing is done.
 */
boolean waitForFileDone() {
    synchronized (waitFileSync) {
        try {
            while (!fileDone)
                waitFileSync.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return fileSuccess;
}

/**
 * Event handler for the file writer.
 */
public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

    if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            fileDone = true;
            waitFileSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            fileDone = true;
            fileSuccess = false;
            waitFileSync.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {
    if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
            || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            stateTransitionOK = true;
            waitSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            stateTransitionOK = false;
            waitSync.notifyAll();
        }
    } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
        evt.getSourceController().stop();
        evt.getSourceController().close();
    }

}
```